# Connect to VPN server when system starts

Tags: startup, openvpn

I can connect to my VPN server with command:

```
 sudo openvpn confyg.ovpn
```

Everything runs fine, but what is the best way to start openvpn client and connect to server when system starts?

Comment: What VPN provider?

Comment: Provider is https://openvpn.net . Connecting to different providers makes different connect commands?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu/Linux are you using? Are you using a desktop or a server? Do you want a GUI solution?

Comment: @vico Just curious... why did you accept the more complicated systemd answer, over my simpler GUI answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `systemd`

In order to configure OpenVPN to autostart using systemd, complete the following steps:

Run the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/openvpn
```

and uncomment, or remove, the “#” in front of

```
AUTOSTART="all"
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the text editor.

Copy the .ovpn file with the desired server location to the ‘/etc/openvpn’ folder:

```
sudo cp /location/whereYouDownloadedConfigfilesTo/confyg.ovpn /etc/openvpn/
```

Edit the .ovpn file you copied in the previous step and change the line ‘auth-user-pass’ to ‘auth-user-pass pass’:

```
sudo nano /etc/openvpn/confyg.ovpn
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the text editor.

In the ‘/etc/openvpn’ folder, create a text file called pass:

```
sudo nano /etc/openvpn/pass
```

and enter your VPN Account ID on the first line and VPN passwordon the 2nd line, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the text editor.

Change the permissions on the pass file to protect the credentials:

```
sudo chmod 400 /etc/openvpn/pass
```

Rename the .ovpn file to ‘client.conf’:

```
sudo mv /etc/openvpn/confyg.ovpn /etc/openvpn/client.conf
```

Enable the Openvpn@ service with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable openvpn@client.service
```

Reload the daemons:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the OpenVPN service:

```
sudo service openvpn@client start
```

Reboot and test if it is working by checking the external IP.

Adapted from: https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/linux/linux-autostart-openvpn-in-systemd-ubuntu/

Hope this helps

Comment: My GUI method seems a lot simpler :-)

Comment: @heynnema There is no doubt about the GUI method is simpler. I have used it in the past. Your answer is very well written. I like GuI answers that include screenshots. They are easier to follow.    I have another solution using `crontab` that is a bit simpler than the systemd based solution.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here we go...

- open the **Network Settings** panel
- click on the + icon that's just to the right of VPN

[image]

- select import from file
- locate your confyg.ovpn file

[image]

- in `terminal` type `nm-connection-editor`
- select Wired Connection
- click on the edit/gear icon

[image]

- select the General tab
- enable **Automatically connect to VPN**
- select the previously imported configuration file in the popup
- save the connection
- reboot

[image]